# Why isn't "ssh localhost nohup echo hello" working?

Tags: ssh, nohup

I think this sums it up:

```
# /usr/bin/nohup echo hello
/usr/bin/nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'

# ssh localhost /usr/bin/nohup echo hello
hello
```

What was happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man nohup` (POSIX)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/nohup.1posix.html):

```
   If  the  standard output is a terminal, all output written by the named
   utility to its standard output shall be appended to the end of the file
   nohup.out  in  the current directory. ...

   If the standard error is a terminal, all output written  by  the  named
   utility  to  its  standard  error  shall be redirected to the same file
   descriptor as the standard output.
```

To stress: ***If* the standard output is a terminal**.

With a simple `ssh nohup echo foo`, standard output isn't a TTY unless you tell SSH to create one:

```
ssh -t localhost nohup echo foo
```

From [`man ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh.1.html):

```
-T   Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
-t   Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute
     arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
     very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
     options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Also see:

- [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/70524)

Comment: Someone give this human an upvote. No idea why you were downvoted in the first place…

Comment: @n.st Probably because my original answer was a bit short. It happens. :D

Comment: Explanation is incomplete: *ssh me@remote echo "Hello" > /home/me/somefile* creates the file alright, while *nohup* cannot create the file . This is what needs to be added to your explanation.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae nonsense. That file will be created irrespective of whether you use `ssh ... nohup`, since it is your local shell that's doing the redirection and creation of that file.

Comment: You just quoted text saying that *nohup* is not invoked when the output file cannot be created... You are contradicting yourself (and only Walt Whitman is allowed to do that).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae that's for `nohup` creating its own output file. (`nohup` saves output in a file.) `nohup` neither knows nor cares about what your local shell is doing, until you tell SSH to allocate a TTY. Even then, if your local shell cannot create the file, it will not start the command, so it's not `nohup` that fails.

Answer (score 5):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30520299/1114687),

> recent versions of ssh started using pipes for non-TTY STDIO

so

> there is no way for a bash script to tell whether a non-tty `ssh` command is being piped or not.

Since `nohup` only springs into action when it detects that `stdout`/`stderr` are connected to a terminal (and does nothing when the output goes to a pipe), and `ssh`'s way of launching it looks like it's being piped, you get the behaviour you're seeing.

---

As [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317712/28235), you can force `ssh` to allocate a `tty` by using the `-t` parameter:

```
$ ssh -t localhost "/usr/bin/nohup /bin/echo foo"
/usr/bin/nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
```